# How to delete a document inside a subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection STUDENTS which has a sub collection PLAYLIST what I want to do is deleting the documents inside the PLAYLIST

this is the code I have tried

```
    const result = await deleteDoc(doc(db, path, dataId));
```

the path is `"Students/student_id/Playlist"`
the dataID is the document i wanted to delete but there are no result when i trigger this action

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the documents inside a sub-collection, you should loop the snapshot and call the `deleteDoc()` method. See code below:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "students", "<student_id>", "playlist"));

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  deleteDoc(doc.ref);
});
```